# Using socket chat with angularjs and ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, ionic-framework

[image]

I have coded this in app.js

```
app.factory('socket',function(socketFactory){
    //Create socket and connect to http://chat.socket.io 
     var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://chat.socket.io');

      mySocket = socketFactory({
        ioSocket: myIoSocket
      });

    return mySocket;
})
```

And in controller.js i have coded this

```
app.controller('ChatController',function(socket,$stateParams,$ionicScrollDelegate,$scope,$sanitize) {

$scope.messages = [];
socket.on('connect',function(){
    //Add user called nickname
    socket.emit('add user',$stateParams.nickname);
    })
})
```

Can please anyone explain how can i connect and test this code in my localhost ionic app and not on the url http://chat.socket.io.I have searched for 2 days straight but couldnt execute this.

If I coded this `var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:8100/#/chat/');` then the error showing is `socket.io.js:3497 GET http://localhost:8100/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LKlIZvc 404 (Not Found)`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: i think your forgot to include your socket factory in your controller mySocket is an variable so declare var before that

Comment: @MohanGopi i have included socket.Please let me edit my code in the question

Comment: so do you get any error

Comment: @MohanGopi yes if i place 'localhost:8100/#/chats' in the path url then this error is shown `GET http://localhost:8100/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LKlIX9B 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: can you show me your full error part and your full code so that  i can have an idea where when wrong

Comment: @MohanGopi yes i can

Comment: @MohanGopi i have executed this when using the url http://chat.socket.io.Can you please tell me just how can i execute in localhost?

Comment: take a look at this tutorial may be this can give you some idea https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/creating-a-real-time-chat-application-with-ionic-2-and-socket-io/

Comment: @MohanGopi i have seen that tutorial but it speaks of angular js 2 and ionic 2.My project is of earlier versions.If you could only tell me how to execute this same code in localhost that would be of great help